# List of Table, Koma-script: how to not have the entire caption?

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, koma-script

I use the KOMA-script to write the thesis and when i call the `\listoftables` I would like to modify some entries.
For example, for the following table:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|cc|cc|cc|cc}     
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 2} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 3} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 4}      
\tabularnewline 
  \hline 
\hline  
$ A $ & & & &  &  & & & 
\tabularnewline             
$ B $ & & & &  &  & & &\
\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{{\sc Size}: Rejection frequencies of asymptotic and bootstrap test. 
The sample $T$ is 1000. 
Note that we use the principal component analysis for A.}
\label{tab:size}
\end{table}
```

I would like only this sentence in the list of table: `{\sc Size}: Rejection frequencies of asymptotic and bootstrap test.`
If you need more information about my `.tex`, let me know.

Comment: `\caption[short one for the LoT]{long one for document}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.